# Can I configure a TP-LINK TL-WR740N as a repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater

My ISP provided me with a new modem that is already a router with WiFi and some ports.

I would like to use my [TP-LINK TL-WR740N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WR740N.html) as a wireless repeater, putting it in another room and connecting to my ISP router using WiFi. Is that possible?

I made it work by connecting it with cables, but I would like to make it wireless.

Comment: Just had a quick scan of the model in Google and it seems it has a WDS (Wireless Distribution System) wireless feature.

Just did a quick Google search for WDS and that is basically another term for repeater, so it looks like it may be possible yes!

Comment: Today, powerline networking is a great choice. You can use the powerline to substitute for the wired link between the router and an additional access point. A pair of AV1200-class adapters can be had for $60 or less.

Comment: Keep in mind that a wireless repeater roughly cuts your bandwidth in half b/c 50% of the time is spent relaying a packet instead of sending the next packet. I would consider moving the ISP's modem if possible, or keeping your router wired (but in WAP mode if possible).

Comment: https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/faq/227/   

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kIMkKizyvM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thsi answer is **WRONG**. Sorry about this. Please neglect it.

---

No, unfortunately you cannot. Your model only has one wireless interface, while a repeater needs two. A single card repeater will wnd up talking to clients half of the time, and to its base station the other half of the time, thus cutting bandwidth in half.

In fact, [its User's Guide](http://www.tp-link.it/Resources/document/TL-WR740N_741ND_User_Guide.pdf) makes no mention of alternative modes like wireless repeater, range extender, wireless bridge, which are all roughly synonims.

The term WDS does indicate its ability to partake in a Wireless Distribution System, however I believe it is meant to indicate that it can act as a base station, not a `relay-station` as required by the OP. Besides, in the manual mentioned above, there is no discussion of WDSes.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I also checked the manual and could not find anything about this.

Comment: Yes, you can. See the answers below.

Answer (score 33):

Yes you can configure your TP-Link WR740N as a repeater/wireless bridge. Following are the basic steps that you need to take to set up one:

- Go to wireless settings page of your WR740N router's web interface, enable the option "Enable WDS Bridging"  and click **Survey**.
- Your bridge router will show you routers to bridge with. Select the appropriate one.
- Make sure that the selected security settings are the one that match with the router that is connected to the ISP and provide a password for it.
- Disable your bridge router's DHCP and restart the router.

Following these steps should allow you to set up your WR740N as a repeater. I have been using it as one without any problem so far.

Comment: this is the right answer

Comment: Right! It can be done.. I just made it work.

Comment: With the above steps, I was able to make it work for tl wr850n as well.

Comment: Yeah this is the correct answer, the only part i was missing to disable the DHCP. This saved me lot of time

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can!

According to this [link](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?faqid=227) provided by TP Link, you cand make the settings. I have multiple TP Link routers at home, all configured as WDS repeaters after this settings and entire network is working fine.

**Follow this steps**:

```
1. Login into root AP or extended AP and enable WDS under: Wireless -> Wireless Settings.
2. Click on Search/Survey button and click Connect to desired SSID Wireless Network.
3. On the password input, put your main SSID Wireless password (should be the same) and Save settings.
4. Disable DHCP under: Wireless -> Wireless Security.
5. Reboot router/AP.
```

**Note**:

```
1. LAN IP of extended router should be different but in the same subnet of the root router;
2. The DHCP Server on extended router should be disabled;
3. WDS bridging only requires the WDS setting on either the root router or the extended router.
```

***note***: The `accepted answer` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I m using it that way. Enable WDS bridge option and give the passkey to the base station. There you go....

Comment: You need to enable WDS in the base station as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes. You can set your WR740N as repeater. I did.
http://blog.jeffcosta.com/2011/09/29/create-a-wireless-n-bridge-with-2-inexpensive-tp-link-routers/
http://nightsatan.blogspot.com/2013/03/tp-link-wr740n-as-wireless-extender-or_26.html
etc

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Attention!

You can set a WR740N as a repeater according to the instructions given by other users before me but you also have to go to the main router and make it aware (there is a special setting that depends of your main router connected directly to the internet) your WR740N exists. If you do not change anything in the main router your WR740N will only work as a repeater for a while (a few hours or days) and then it will stop unexpectedly.

WR740N does not work elegantly like a range extender (a NETGEAR for example) where there is no need to modify any settings in the main router.