# Can I turn a tl-wr740n router into an access point?

Tags: router

It's a router.

I want the router to get internet access from another router and forward that to my desktop.

How do I find out if it's possible or not say from the spec

If so how?

Comment: Do you plan to wire it to the router or does it have to connect wirelessly? Does the router you're using it with support WDS and can you configure WDS on the other router? Do you just want Internet access or are you trying to extend the LAN? (I think you're a bit confused. If you turned it into an access point, it would extend the LAN, not provide Internet access. If you want it to provide Internet connections for multiple devices with just a single client connection, well that's what a router does, not what an access point does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's possible. I should specify, that you appear to want is a Wireless Bridge, which will, in laymen's terms "convert" a remote WiFi source to Ethernet ports.

Take a look at this answer for a Wireless Bridge: https://superuser.com/a/716730/162557

An Access point is somewhat the opposite, where you attach 2 routers with an Ethernet cable, and the 2nd Router Provides a WiFi signal as well. Both these options are often used to extend a wireless network.

Comment: For those who want to configure it as an access point: here is a guide from TP-Link: http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-417.html