# WDS Bridging with a TP-Link TL-WR740N

Tags: networking, router, bridge, wds, wireless-extender

I've been trying to use my TP-Link TL-WR740N as a WDS Bridge (range extender); I've followed guides. I've enabled WDS, scanned for the network, put in all the network information, changed IP address to 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.1 being the default gateway of the base router), and disabled DHCP.  After all that I reconnect to the base router and try to access 192.168.0.2. Connection gets refused. I bring the router back and attempt to change settings with a LAN cable, and Windows cannot identify the router. I've run out of ideas to fix it. Just looking for some help to get it working. I'm not sure if I missed a setting or if this router just isn't compatible (even though it has the setting). I really need this to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/678527/can-i-configure-a-tp-link-tl-wr740n-as-a-repeater