# Would TP-LINK TL-WR740N used as repeater will cut bandwidth in half?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, repeater

I have successfully configured TP-LINK WR740N as a repeater as instructed in [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/716730/222026) as well as on the official [tp-link site](https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/faq/227/). Root router is same model.

However, when I did that, although I get better range the speed drops in half, or less. At the same spot, if I connect to the **root router** I would get 60-70Mbps, while when I connect to the **repeater** I am getting 25-30 Mbps at best.

Any idea why this is happening, can it be fixed or is it expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is to be expected

[Wireless Repeaters](https://www.screenbeam.com/wifihelp/wifibooster/wifi-extenders-beat-wifi-repeaters-every-time/#:%7E:text=Because%20the%20connection%20to%20your,it%20is%20susceptible%20to%20interference.&text=A%20WiFi%20repeater%20connects%20to%20a%20router%20and%20wireless%20devices,leads%20to%20slower%20connection%20speeds.)

> A WiFi repeater connects to a router and wireless devices on the same
> frequency. This means that your wireless devices will only get half of
> the bandwidth available. Less bandwidth leads to slower connection
> speeds.

The traffic back and forth when packets are sent also reduce bandwidth.

I avoid this by using a good Access Point (Ubiquiti) which I wired to the main network.

I get full wireless speed with this arrangement.